# How to dynamically select columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Lets assume i ran a random Forest model and i get the variable importance info as below:

```
set.seed(121)
ImpMeasure<-data.frame(mod.varImp$importance)
ImpMeasure$Vars<-row.names(ImpMeasure)
ImpMeasure.df<-ImpMeasure[order(-ImpMeasure$Overall),]
row.names(ImpMeasure.df)<-NULL
class(ImpMeasure.df)
ImpMeasure.df<-ImpMeasure.df[,c(2,1)] # so now we have the importance variable info in a data frame
ImpMeasure.df

                   Vars        Overall
1            num_voted_users 100.000000
2     num_critic_for_reviews  58.961441
3       num_user_for_reviews  56.500707
4       movie_facebook_likes  50.680318
5  cast_total_facebook_likes  30.012205
6                      gross  27.652559
7     actor_3_facebook_likes  24.094213
8     actor_2_facebook_likes  19.633290
9                 imdb_score  16.063007
10    actor_1_facebook_likes  15.848972
11                  duration  11.886036
12                    budget  11.853066
13                title_year   7.804387
14   director_facebook_likes   7.318787
15      facenumber_in_poster   1.868376
16              aspect_ratio   0.000000
```

Now If i decide that i want only top 5 variables for further analysis then in do this:

```
library(dplyr)
top.var<-ImpMeasure.df[1:5,] %>% select(Vars)
top.var

                  Vars
1           num_voted_users
2    num_critic_for_reviews
3      num_user_for_reviews
4      movie_facebook_likes
5 cast_total_facebook_likes
```

How can use this info to select these var only from the original dataset (given below) without spelling out the actual variable names but using say the output of `top.var`....how to use dplyr `select` function for this..

My original dataset is like this:

```
 num_critic_for_reviews duration director_facebook_likes actor_3_facebook_likes
1                723      178                       0                    855
2                302      169                     563                   1000
3                602      148                       0                    161
4                813      164                   22000                  23000
5                255       95                     131                    782
6                462      132                     475                    530
 actor_1_facebook_likes     gross num_voted_users cast_total_facebook_likes
1                1000      760505847      886204                      4834
2                40000     309404152      471220                     48350
3                11000     200074175      275868                     11700
4                27000     448130642      1144337                    106759
5                131       228830            8                       143
6                640       73058679      212204                      1873
 facenumber_in_poster num_user_for_reviews    budget title_year
1                    0                 3054 237000000       2009
2                    0                 1238 300000000       2007
3                    1                  994 245000000       2015
4                    0                 2701 250000000       2012
5                    0                   97  26000000       2002
6                    1                  738 263700000       2012
 actor_2_facebook_likes imdb_score aspect_ratio movie_facebook_likes cluster
1                    936        7.9         1.78              33000       2
2                   5000        7.1         2.35                  0       3
3                    393        6.8         2.35              85000       2
4                  23000        8.5         2.35             164000       3
5                     12        7.1         1.85                  0       1
6                    632        6.6         2.35              24000       2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
movies.imp<-moviesdf.cluster%>% select(one_of(top.vars),cluster)
head(movies.imp)
 ##   num_voted_users num_user_for_reviews num_critic_for_reviews
 ## 1          886204            3054                    723
 ## 2          471220            1238                    302
 ## 3          275868            994                    602
 ## 4         1144337            2701                    813
 ## 5               8            127                     37
 ## 6          212204            738                    462
 ##   movie_facebook_likes cast_total_facebook_likes cluster
 ## 1                33000                     4834       1
 ## 2                    0                     48350      1
 ## 3                85000                     11700      1
 ## 4               164000                    106759      1
 ## 5                    0                       143      2
 ## 6                24000                      1873      1
```

That done!

Answer (score 0):

Hadley provided the answer to that [here](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/528258673546522625):

```
select_(df, .dots = top.var)
```